# Google API search using phone number Error:

Tags: python, api, google-api

On the documentation page of [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) its mentioned that we can use inputtype = phonenumber to search using phonenumber

but when i use the get command i get an error invalid request

**Query**

```
MY_API_KEY = '<my api key>

gurl = https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=+14169743940&inputtype=textquery&key=MY_API_KEY'

 r = requests.get(gurl)
 jdata = r.json()
 googleoutput = jdata["status"]
 print(jdata)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
 ...: r = requests.get(gurl)
jdata = r.json()
googleoutput = jdata["status"]
print(jdata)
{'candidates': [], 'debug_log': {'line': []}, 'status': 'INVALID_REQUEST'}
```

Comment: phonenumber +14169743940 belongs to royal bank of canada toronto

Comment: Guess: the url parameters should be urlencoded (especially the phone number, which includes a '+') and the value of `inputtype` should be 'phonenumber'.

Comment: Thats what not working for me, when i type in inputquery=phonenumber, it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

The phone number must be format of E.164. For example, you can search this number %2B16174951585, it will return the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests 

MY_API_KEY = 'Your API Key'

gurl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=+14169743940&inputtype=textquery&key='+str(MY_API_KEY)

r = requests.get(gurl)
jdata = r.json()
googleoutput = jdata["status"]
print(jdata)
```

Enter Your API Key in the place of 'Your API Key'.
Your problem is the URL gurl, you need to pass the above API key variable to the URL or verify your API from [console](https://console.cloud.google.com) if still no results.

Output:

```
{u'status': u'ZERO_RESULTS', u'candidates': [], u'debug_log': {u'line': []}}
```

Comment: I dont have  problem with my api_key, i have done the same, but for inputtype = textquery, i want input type as phone number